# How to allow bolding, underlining and italics in textarea

Tags: php, html

I'm currently using `nl2br()` when reading text from a database. Unfortunately, if I wrap some text within with  or  the text doesn't bold it and shows the code still. How do I allow for some html to go through and be rendered correctly?

I'm currently getting this outputted from the database...

`<b>Blah blah text</b>`

when I'd like it to show bold instead of the tags still existing.

For ex:

In the database I have a dummy post to test if the database works.

The database read...

```
Hello and welcome to the forums! 

&lt;b&gt;Test&lt;/b&gt;
```

That information is being read back through nl2br() as..

```
Hello and welcome to the forums! 

<b>Test</b>
```

I'd like test to be bolded.

Comment: no idea what your asking

Comment: You may need to look for http://www.tinymce.com/. 
Or I think if you want to format your content, you may also need to look for Markdown editor.

Comment: Is there a simpler way that I can do it without a plugin? I don't want a bunch of code that won't be used. All I need is the output to be bolded, italiced, or underlined when wrapped in the html tags.

Comment: if you put a break in the middle or end of your example you will still get bold text, so i'm still not clear. What's an actual example of text from the db, and then the html produced.

Comment: I'm very confused. You say you don't want formatting, but `I'd like test to be bolded.` is formatting. Can you explain what your desired output is?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to format text in text area. You may try using div and then ContentEditable

Here are references

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.contentEditable
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla

Comment: I'm not looking to format text inside a text area. Just the outputted text when read.

Comment: in that case, just use div instead of text area

Comment: I output the database info into an array and call it in a div but the text isn't formatted. I don't know why.

Comment: try innerhtml. `divdom.innerHTML='<b>Test</b>'`

Answer (score 0):

You can't. HTML `<textarea>` elements can only contain plain text.

You will need to use a Javascript rich text editor component such as [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) or [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

Comment: I'm not looking to format text inside a text area. Just the outputted text when read.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotta be talking about this: http://php.net/manual/tr/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: It's already outputted correctly but the html isn't being formatted.