# how to make part of an output in italic - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, output, italic

There quite a few questions on the web and on this website about making italic fonts, but non mentions how to italic only part of a string.

In my case, there is a form I enter the book title, the author's name and the number sold. After clicking a button I want author's name and the number sold be normal but the book title to be in italic in the text area (output).

Coding for form:

```
<label for="txtName">Author Name</label>
<input type="text" id="txtName" size="50" placeholder="Eg, Darwin" maxlength="50">

<label for="txtTitle">Book Title</label>
<input type="text" id="txtTitle" size="40" placeholder="Eg, The Origin of Species" style="font-style:italic" maxlength="100">

<label for="txtNumber">Number Sold</label>
<input type="text" id="txtNumber" size="4" placeholder="Eg, 50000" maxlength="9">
```

When the user enters the book title, as they type title looks italic but the value will not stay in italic.  After the required calculations is done at the end I want the title, author and the number shown in this order:

```
bTitle = bookForm.txtTitle.value;
bName = bookForm.txtName.value;
bNumber = bookForm.txtNumber.value;

concatBook = bTitle+" by "+bName+" sold "+bNumber+" Copies."
```

This concatBook will be shown in a text area via a function.

The only thing I want to be in italic is bTitle.

Thanks for reading my question

Comment: javascript does not keep text styling. You need to do that with an html tag and/or css (like with your input field). See here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108318/css-html-what-is-the-correct-way-to-make-text-italic also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074391/how-to-allow-bolding-underlining-and-italics-in-textarea.

Comment: Could try to use the Javascript method `italics()` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_italics.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add italic style (or wathever you want) you need to wrap the text you want to style in `span` tags. But you can't insert HTML inside a `textarea`. You should use a `<div contenteditable="true"></div>` instead.

Take a look at this **[minimal demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/p0rheftz/)**.

HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

CSS:

```
span{
    font-style: italic;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var concatBook = "<span>by</span> sold Copies."
$('div').html(concatBook);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but there is a problem here that it shows the work 'by' in italic not the value it holds, for instance if the bTitle holds the book's title, "<span>bTitle</span>" obviously it shows bTitle in italic not the vaue it carries.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to make the bTitle's value italic

Comment: My answer is a "minimal example". In your case you can do this: `concatBook = "<span>"+bTitle+"</span> by "+bName+" sold "+bNumber+" Copies."`. See a [new demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/p0rheftz/1/).

Comment: Oh man, you rock. Thanks a lot. I was struggling with that for two weeks!

Comment: @aryazdani I'm glad for you!

Comment: It works perfectly fine, but I have a new problem with that! it doesn't call the  DisplayHarvardBook(concatBook), it shows the result in a new page in stead of the text area defined in  DisplayHarvardBook();

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean :( Maybe you should elaborate a new question or explain better what you have and what you want.